# How call Magento 2 module by url (or add route in module)?

Tags: magento2, php, controllers, router

I wrote module in Magento 2 and this is my `/etc/frontend/routes.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="test" frontName="test">
            <module name="Arthur_Test" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

and I have to access to my module from external script to get some data he generate. That data is in `app/code/Arthur/Test/storage/data.txt`

I cant get that data by exact url `(example.com/app/code/Arthur/Test/storage/data.txt)` because of 403 Forbidden so I want to call method in my module. How can I do it ?

url `example.com/test/` give me 404 Not Found

Comment: Have you create controller file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn how to create a module. For starters, I can help you create a basic module:

> app/code/Arthur/Test/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Arthur_Test',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Arthur/Test/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Arthur_Test" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

> app/code/Arthur/Test/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="test" id="test">
            <module name="Arthur_Test"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> app/code/Arthur/Test/Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php


namespace Arthur\Test\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Execute view action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "My controller has been called";die;
        //return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is working, i am trying to call my phtml and block that isn't working the way you have done controller i have it too and if i put die; it works as well not going to my phtml class

Answer (score 0):

Make router name storage

```
 <route frontName="storage" id="storage">
```

The path to controller should be 
 app/code/Arthur/Test/Controller/Storage/Data.php

and the file

```
<?php namespace Arthur\Test\Controller\Storage;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
  echo "test";
}
```

Now if you call  example.com/storage/data  it will work