# Error with own module to show frontend views

Tags: magento2, module, frontend, frontend-error, error-log

My aim is to generate a few frontend views with an phtml for each view. I developed a module for that.

File: Routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="micuenta" frontName="micuenta">
            <module name="MyVendor_Intranet"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

File: Controller/Index/index.php

```
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context  $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

/**
* Mi Cuenta.
*
* @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
*/
public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0', true);
    return $resultPage;
}}
```

But I get an apache error:

> [Mon Mar 16 17:54:22.638389 2020] [:error] [pid 4074] [client
>   46.27.23.194:62372] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to MyVendor\Intranet\Controller\Index\Index::__construct()
>   must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context,
>   instance of Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given,
>   called in
>   /var/vhosts/algsa.es/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php
>   on line 93 and defined in
>   /var/vhosts/algsa.es/app/code/Auren/Intranet/Controller/Index/index.php:15\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/vhosts/algsa.es/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(93):
>   Auren\Intranet\Controller\Index\Index->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager))\n#1
>   /var/vhosts/algsa.es/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(88):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Auren\\Intranet\\...',
>   Array)\n#2
>   /var/vhosts/algsa.es/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(57):
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Auren\\Intranet\\...',
>   Array)\n#3 /var/vhosts/algsa.es/ve in
>   /var/vhosts/algsa.es/app/code/Auren/Intranet/Controller/Index/index.php
>   on line 15

My page gets a blank view and apache log registers the error.

PD: Very similar approach from [How call Magento 2 module by url (or add route in module)?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/231727/how-call-magento-2-module-by-url-or-add-route-in-module)

Comment: hi, there did you create all the required files for the module ?

Comment: You can follow the below guide to create custom module   https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/

Answer (score 0):

try below code

**File: etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="micuenta" frontName="micuenta">
            <module name="MyVendor_Intranet" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**File: Controller/Index/index.php**

```
namespace MyVendor\Intranet\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\ForwardFactory
     */
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $pageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->_pageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;

    }
}
```

Create all the required files for the module like layout, Block

Then hit below commands

```
sudo rm -rf var/*
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/*
sudo rm -rf generated/*

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
sudo php bin/magento ca:cl
sudo php bin/magento ca:fl
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/(project name)/
```

Comment: create all the required files for the module.

Comment: I already had that, it is the same code, don't see the difference. But I also tried without success.

Comment: i just update my ans please check

Comment: I tried that and same apache error

Answer (score 0):

I think you have done right but just forgot to clear everything in **generated/code** folder.

It is the place where the new dependency injection is generated and located.

Just try and enjoy.

Comment: I tried that and same apache error